# iOS: syntax to retrieve value of attribute in array?

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have an array of user objects, one of which is stored in a property `_selectedUser`.  When I log it out, it displays as :

```
{
    uid = 5;
    uname = xxxx;
}
```

However, when I try to access the uid with the following, I get an error:

```
NSNumber *useridnum = _selectedUser.uid;
```

Error:

> [NSKnownKeysDictionary1 uid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What is the proper syntax to retrieve value for uid?

Comment: It looks like selectedUser is actually a dictionary? does _selectedUser[@"uid"] work?

Comment: What array? You have a dictionary. Update your question with the code that creates and assigns the value for `_selectedUser`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the key as a property on the dictionary, not as a value it contains.

<s>As D.C. suggested in the comments, use this code:</s>

```
NSNumber *useridnum = _selectedUser[@"uid];
```

Or:

```
NSNumber *useridnum = [_selectedUser objectForKey:@"uid"];
```

You said in the comments that the object is an NSManagedObject.  I'm not familiar with Core Data, but it looks like you need to use `valueForKey:`:

```
NSNumber *useridnum = [_selectedUser valueForKey:@"uid"];
```

An `NSDictionary` does not store the keys directly as properties; it stores them in some kind of private data structure.  It wouldn't be possible to dynamically store keys as properties without messing with the runtime, and then only a very limited set of strings could be used as keys (instead of basically every possible object), because the keys would have to be C identifiers.

You get this error because when you tried to access the key as a property, the system sent a message to the object saying to call the getter method for the property, but that getter method didn't exist, so the app crashed.

Comment: It is not a dictionary currently.  It is a NSManagedObject for a user.

Comment: @zztop You should have specified that in your question then.  I'm not very familiar with Core Data, but, looking at the docs, it seems like you need to use `valueForKey:` then.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer question.  I will play around with valueforkey.

Comment: @zztop You're welcome!  In the future, please try to include all of the relevant information in the question.  See [mcve].

Comment: The following code did the trick: NSNumber *useridnum = [_selectedUser valueForKey:@"uid"];  Thanks for valueForKey suggestion